# Problems installing PEAR MDB2 with MAMP

Tags: php, linux, macos, pear, mamp

I've installed a copy of MAMP on my macbook so I can run my php/mysql based website locally.

The MAMP package itself seems to work fine but I needed the PEAR MDB2 Package.

I did the following to install

```
pear install MDB2
pear install MDB2_Driver_mysql
pear channel-update pear.php.net
```

All apparently worked and if I try again, they say already installed.

The php include path set in php.ini also looks to be correct:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php"
```

Yet after restarting the server and trying to hit my site, I still get

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'MDB2.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/config.php on line 5

Answer (score 1):

Is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php` the root directory for PEAR?  That doesn't sound right.  Run the command `pear config-get php_dir`, it will tell you where the PEAR root directory is (despite the misleading configuration name).  The default is `/usr/share/pear`.